# detecting amount of senders connected to chromecast

Tags: android, google-cast

As title says how do i count the amount of sender devices connected to a chromecast device or receiver.

Can i do this via a `RouteInfo` or `CastDevice` instance? or will i need to implement my own custom namespace for this on the receiver end?

i have not seen any method so for on castdevice or routeinfo that can help me?

i grab the castdevice or routeinfo by custom methods that i have implemented in the cast companion library

```
/**
 * Always check for null when using this
 * @return The cast device which the sender is currently connected to. CastDevice contains basic info. for more advanced info use getCurrentRoute
 */
public CastDevice getCurrentCastDevice(){
    return mSelectedCastDevice;
}

/**
 * Always check for null when using this
 * @return The routeinfo the cast device is currently connoected to. RouteInfo contains more info than a CastDevice.
 */
public RouteInfo getCurrentRoute(){
    return mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute();
}

/**
 * Always check for null when using this
 *
 */
public MediaRouter getCurrentMediaRouter(){
    return mMediaRouter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senders do not have that information. You need to get that information from your receiver, if needed (say, using a custom namespace and data channel). Out of curiosity, why would you need that on the sender, what is the use case?

Comment: My intention was to detect wether to just disconnect the sender or disconnect the sender and leave the receiver application. But after searching a while I stumbled upon a code snippet provided on the cast developers website

Comment: Yes, receiver SDK was updated to include a "reason" for disconnect in onSenderDisconnected() that can help you with that decision.